# Coefficient of determination (R^2)

Tags: regression, r-squared

What do we mean when we say that R^2 is he proportion of variability in Y explained by X, Since R^2 = (TSS-RSS)/RSS, So o what basis do we consider TSS as total variability and RSS as Unexplained variability and then we conclude that TSS - RSS is the explained variability?

Comment: Have you done a customary google search or search on CV? There are so many posts here dealing with the interpretation of $R^2.$ Have a look, for instance, in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198654/coefficient-of-determination).